# Matrix of transformation $F(x,y,z) = (x,y,z)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

[image]

I have proven that $S$ is also a basis. But I am not sure about the second one. Is it just identity matrix $3\times 3$ as we don't change anything?

Comment: Yes, the representation of the identity transformation with respect to *any* basis is the identity matrix.

Comment: Right, I thought so. Thanks

Comment: In the worst case, you can always say that $F(v_1+v_2)=F(v_1)+F(v_2)=v_1+v_2=1\cdot(v_1+v_2)+0\cdot(v_2+v_3)+0\cdot(v_3+v_1)$, and similar for $v_2+v_3$ and $v_3+v_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The representation of the identity transformation is the identity matrix no matter what (ordered) basis is chosen.

Answer (score 1):

The linear transformation  $$F(x,y,z) = (x,y,z)$$ is the identity transformation and its matrix with respect to any basis is the identity $3\times 3$ matrix.

$$M=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$